# get_post_custom_values not working

Tags: custom-field, get-posts

I have made a custom template to show the posts in "Products" category in a single page.I have some custom fields.I need to show the values of the custom fields in the page. I have used the get_post_custom_values as the following but i get an error as

```
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\wamp\www\SampleSite\wp-content\themes\TwentyElevenChildTheme\products.php on line 11
```

The code for products.php is as follows.

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Product Template
*/
?>
<?php get_header(); ?>
<div id="content" class="narrowcolumn">
  <?php $recent = new WP_Query("cat=4&showposts=10"); while($recent->have_posts()) :$recent->the_post();?>
  <?php $key_values = get_post_custom_values("Description"); ?>
  <?php foreach($key_values as $key => $value )?>
  <?php echo  "$key  => $value("Description") <br />";?>
  <?php endwhile; ?>
</div>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

I am not able to find what the error is.Someone please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It most probably means that no custom post values have been retrieved for the key `Description` that you used. According to the [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_custom_values), `Returns nothing if no such key exists, or none is entered.`

Try adding `print_r($key_values);` on the line just after `get_post_custom_values("Description");` and check if any value is retrieved.

To skip this warning(when you don't have any custom post values associated to a post), you should check if `$key_values` [is an array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-array.php) before doing the `foreach`. And don't forget to escape your double quotes.

```
if( is_array( $key_values ) ){
  foreach($key_values as $key => $value );
  echo  "$key  => $value(\"Description\") <br />"; #You should escape your double quotes here!
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
<?php $key_values = get_post_custom_values("Description",get_the_ID()); ?>
```

**ps:** you should use `posts_per_page` instead of `showposts` in `WP_Query()`.

You can use also debug it with

```
 print_r(get_post_custom(get_the_ID()));
```

to find out all the custom fields in your post.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_custom